# Http Analyzer plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have used Http Analyzer in JDeveloper, is there any plugin for Eclipse editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **TCP/IP Monitor** view. (Window>Show View>Other... and then Debug>TCP/IP Monitor).